# How exactly does one perform tahajjud prayer?

Tags: salat, tahajjud

Some deaf people do tahajjud prayer.  We sometimes do it, but we heard that tahajjud prayer is not as easy as we think, so we would learn about tahajjud prayer.

Can you tell us what to do exactly by performing tahajjud prayer, please?

Answer (score 3):

You pray tahajjud prayer as any other prayer.  It's an optional prayer, done between isha and fajr, and is of two rakat.  You can recite as much quran as you like, there's no stipulation of it being long or short.  It's up to you to pray however length you desire.  Easy and simple.